# How do I use two clusters in a keycloak Kubernetes environment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Key Clock version 17.0.1 and I'm going to run two pods with replicaCount 2 on Helmchart.

However, after logging in, type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR error occurs on one pod.

Additional suspicious error messages are as follows.

1. Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2. no members discovered after 2002 ms: creating cluster as coordinator

How do I modify the help chart?